# Flutter Web with Firebase Auth not working in local but works when deployed in cloud

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin, flutter-web

I was trying out this example with firebase_auth and flutter web.

https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/tree/master/packages/firebase_auth/firebase_auth/example

I used GoogleSign with all the relevant setup. So it opened up the google signin window and let me sign in. Then the code doesn't execute beyond this line.

```
final GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
```

I deployed the same on firebase hosting , and it worked.

So how do I test authentication in local ?

Answer (score 3):

flutter run -d web-server --web-port 5000

solved the problem.

Comment: Bro... I have the total opposite problem and can't figure it out... It works when I do this ```flutter run -d web-server --web-port 5000``` but when it's deployed it's not working at all... Can't figure it out.. Any ideas? I have both my URIs in the OAuth panel

Comment: I figured it out... I had the wrong CLIENT-ID in my <meta> tag,

Comment: mine is weird. once i input the email in the text field, it says browser is not secure. but the url is already in the authorized domain whitelist.

Comment: @chitgoks same happening with me. Did you come around any solution?

Comment: flutter run -d web-server --web-port 5000
This worked for me on local!

Comment: @Chris did you figure out? I am also stuck on the hosted thing. My app runs fine on local, doesn't show the google sign in pop up when hosted.

Comment: @WaleedArshad yes. when you run -d chrome, and a browser shows up, do not use that because it gets identified as not secure. open a normal chrome. if you use run -d web-server then all is well.

Comment: @Chris I am facing the same issue. Everything works fine in local host but when hosted on server, it doesn't work. How did you manage to solve that problem? Please elaborately explain as it might solve my problem

Comment: @JuzerTaherTotanawala have you solved the problem?

Comment: Nope @YasineRomdhane

Comment: You can check allowed URI's from "OAuth 2.0 Client IDs" on Google cloud's API Credentials. Your "localhost:" should be defined at this location.